# Unknown argument "absolute" for function "asset(path, package_name)"

Tags: php, symfony, migration

i have a project that used to work under symfony 2.8 but when i upgraded to symfony 3.2 i get this error

```
Unknown argument "absolute" for function "asset_version(path, package_name)".
```

Here is the stack trace

```
 Twig_Error_Syntax: Unknown argument "absolute" for function "asset_version(path, package_name)".
    at n/a
        in C:\wamp\www\Syslife_upgrade\src\MamdaIT\ComptabiliteBundle/Resources/views/Comptabilite/individuel/editionDetailCotisation.html.twig line 5

    at Twig_Node_Expression_Call->getArguments(array(object(AssetExtension), 'getAssetVersion'), object(Twig_Node))
        in C:\wamp\www\Syslife_upgrade\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Node\Expression\Call.php line 88

    at Twig_Node_Expression_Call->compileArguments(object(Twig_Compiler))
        in C:\wamp\www\Syslife_upgrade\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Node\Expression\Call.php line 41

    at Twig_Node_Expression_Call->compileCallable(object(Twig_Compiler))
        in C:\wamp\www\Syslife_upgrade\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Node\Expression\Function.php line 41

    at Twig_Node_Expression_Function->compile(object(Twig_Compiler))
        in C:\wamp\www\Syslife_upgrade\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Compiler.php line 98

    at Twig_Compiler->subcompile(object(Twig_Node_Expression_Function))
        in C:\wamp\www\Syslife_upgrade\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Node\Expression\Binary.php line 29

    at Twig_Node_Expression_Binary->compile(object(Twig_Compiler))
        in C:\wamp\www\Syslife_upgrade\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Compiler.php line 98

    at Twig_Compiler->subcompile(object(Twig_Node_Expression_Binary_Concat))
        in C:\wamp\www\Syslife_upgrade\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Node\Expression\Call.php line 81

    at Twig_Node_Expression_Call->compileArguments(object(Twig_Compiler))
        in C:\wamp\www\Syslife_upgrade\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Node\Expression\Call.php line 41

    at Twig_Node_Expression_Call->compileCallable(object(Twig_Compiler))
        in C:\wamp\www\Syslife_upgrade\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Node\Expression\Filter.php line 37

    at Twig_Node_Expression_Filter->compile(object(Twig_Compiler))
        in C:\wamp\www\Syslife_upgrade\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Compiler.php line 98

    at Twig_Compiler->subcompile(object(Twig_Node_Expression_Filter))
        in C:\wamp\www\Syslife_upgrade\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Node\Print.php line 30

    at Twig_Node_Print->compile(object(Twig_Compiler))
        in C:\wamp\www\Syslife_upgrade\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Node.php line 117

    at Twig_Node->compile(object(Twig_Compiler))
        in C:\wamp\www\Syslife_upgrade\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Node.php line 117

    at Twig_Node->compile(object(Twig_Compiler))
        in C:\wamp\www\Syslife_upgrade\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Compiler.php line 98

    at Twig_Compiler->subcompile(object(Twig_Node_Body))
        in C:\wamp\www\Syslife_upgrade\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Node\Module.php line 301

    at Twig_Node_Module->compileDisplay(object(Twig_Compiler))
        in C:\wamp\www\Syslife_upgrade\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Node\Module.php line 99

    at Twig_Node_Module->compileTemplate(object(Twig_Compiler))
        in C:\wamp\www\Syslife_upgrade\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Node\Module.php line 71

    at Twig_Node_Module->compile(object(Twig_Compiler))
        in C:\wamp\www\Syslife_upgrade\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Compiler.php line 87

    at Twig_Compiler->compile(object(Twig_Node_Module))
        in C:\wamp\www\Syslife_upgrade\var\cache\dev\classes.php line 5432

    at Twig_Environment->compile(object(Twig_Node_Module))
        in C:\wamp\www\Syslife_upgrade\var\cache\dev\classes.php line 5441

    at Twig_Environment->compileSource(object(Twig_Source))
        in C:\wamp\www\Syslife_upgrade\var\cache\dev\classes.php line 5286

    at Twig_Environment->loadTemplate('ComptabiliteBundle:Comptabilite:individuel/editionDetailCotisation.html.twig')
        in C:\wamp\www\Syslife_upgrade\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig\TwigEngine.php line 126

    at Symfony\Bridge\Twig\TwigEngine->load('ComptabiliteBundle:Comptabilite:individuel/editionDetailCotisation.html.twig')
        in C:\wamp\www\Syslife_upgrade\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig\TwigEngine.php line 50

    at Symfony\Bridge\Twig\TwigEngine->render('ComptabiliteBundle:Comptabilite:individuel/editionDetailCotisation.html.twig', array('exercices' => array('2014', 2015, 2016, 2017), 'cotisations' => array(object(CotisationIndividuelle), object(CotisationIndividuelle), object(CotisationIndividuelle), object(CotisationIndividuelle), object(CotisationIndividuelle), object(CotisationIndividuelle), object(CotisationIndividuelle)), 'contrat' => object(RetraiteContrat)))
        in C:\wamp\www\Syslife_upgrade\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine.php line 50

    at Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine->render('ComptabiliteBundle:Comptabilite:individuel/editionDetailCotisation.html.twig', array('exercices' => array('2014', 2015, 2016, 2017), 'cotisations' => array(object(CotisationIndividuelle), object(CotisationIndividuelle), object(CotisationIndividuelle), object(CotisationIndividuelle), object(CotisationIndividuelle), object(CotisationIndividuelle), object(CotisationIndividuelle)), 'contrat' => object(RetraiteContrat)))
        in C:\wamp\www\Syslife_upgrade\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller.php line 213

    at Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller->renderView('ComptabiliteBundle:Comptabilite:individuel/editionDetailCotisation.html.twig', array('exercices' => array('2014', 2015, 2016, 2017), 'cotisations' => array(object(CotisationIndividuelle), object(CotisationIndividuelle), object(CotisationIndividuelle), object(CotisationIndividuelle), object(CotisationIndividuelle), object(CotisationIndividuelle), object(CotisationIndividuelle)), 'contrat' => object(RetraiteContrat)))
        in C:\wamp\www\Syslife_upgrade\src\MamdaIT\ComptabiliteBundle\Controller\ComptabiliteController.php line 706

    at MamdaIT\ComptabiliteBundle\Controller\ComptabiliteController->editionDetailCotisation(object(Request), '1194')
        in  line 

    at call_user_func_array(array(object(ComptabiliteController), 'editionDetailCotisation'), array(object(Request), '1194'))
        in C:\wamp\www\Syslife_upgrade\var\cache\dev\classes.php line 4229

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1)
        in C:\wamp\www\Syslife_upgrade\var\cache\dev\classes.php line 4184

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)
        in C:\wamp\www\Syslife_upgrade\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel.php line 168

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
        in C:\wamp\www\Syslife_upgrade\web\app_dev.php line 29
```

And finally here are the lines in my code that throw this exceptions

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="{{ app.request.schemeAndHttpHost ~ asset('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css', absolute=true) }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="{{ app.request.schemeAndHttpHost ~  asset('assets/css/style.css' , absolute=true) }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="{{ app.request.schemeAndHttpHost ~  asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css', absolute=true) }}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="{{ app.request.schemeAndHttpHost ~  asset('assets/css/AdminLTE.min.css', absolute=true) }}"/>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue ?

Comment: i remplaced `asset('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css', absolute=true) ` By `absolute_url('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css') `  and it worked just fine